# How do I move a php call to another div and have it still work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've looked around a bit, and found issues similar to mine, but not quite the same. I have a page template that is laid out in 4 columns in HTML. Inside column 4, I have a php function echoing a gallery of images.

```
    <div id="homepage-layout">

        <div id="homepage-column-1">
            <div class="homepage-small"><?php echo get_homepage_img_small_1(); ?></div>
            <div class="homepage-small"><?php echo get_homepage_img_small_2(); ?></div>
            <div class="homepage-small"><?php echo get_homepage_img_small_3(); ?></div>
        </div><!-- End Column 1 -->

        <div id="homepage-column-2">
            <div class="homepage-large-left"><?php putRevSlider("homepage"); ?></div>
        </div><!-- End Column 2 -->

        <div id="homepage-column-3">
            <div class="homepage-med"><?php echo get_homepage_img_med_1(); ?></div>
            <div class="homepage-med"><?php echo get_homepage_img_med_2(); ?></div>
        </div>

        <div id="homepage-column-4">
            <div class="homepage-large-right"><?php putRevSlider("home_small"); ?></div>
        </div><!-- End Column 4 -->

    </div>
```

I'm using jQuery to change the layout of the site based on the width of the window.

```
    var column3 = $("#homepage-column-3").contents();
    var column4 = $("#homepage-column-4").contents();
    var swapped = false;

    $(window).on('resize', function() {   
        if( $(window).width() <= 700 && !swapped){
            $("#homepage-column-3").html(column4);
            $("#homepage-column-4").html(column3);
            swapped = true;
        } else if( $(window).width() > 700) {
            $("#homepage-column-3").html(column3);
            $("#homepage-column-4").html(column4);
            swapped = false;
        }
    });
```

However, when the window size triggers the jQuery, the RevSlider from Column 4 freezes on the image it was displaying at the time, and the only way to get it running again is to refresh the page.

Any thoughts? Or, if this question has been answered already, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Could be a jQuery conflict.

Comment: Does the RevSlider javascript use the name or class of the column? with that changing it might not be able to find the picture.

Comment: You probably need dynamic binding of your gallery / RevSlider as the newly added / swapped element does not have the plugin binded to it. You could also use flexbox instead to easily manipulate the order but that would depend on your browser requirements.

Comment: If you replace the html you would need to reinitalize the slider. Stored references to the elements are gone

Comment: After looking at it, I think using flexbox would work. I'll try it out and let you know the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jeroen had the right idea. I was able to take the 4 columns, and split them into 2 chunks. I was then able to make them both flex containers, and with a of media query, was able to make the columns swap places while keeping the RevSlider initialized.

Thanks to all for your help!